# Extract all links which ends with .js extension in html page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to extract all links that ends with .js within html page.I am able to fetch links that are within script tag
but how could i fetch links from properties like {"yui":"http://l.yimg.com/nn/lib/metro/g/uicontrib/yui/yui_3.4.1.js"}.
I want this to be done in php

Comment: Maybe you should post the code that you used to fetch link in a script tag so we know what your up to.

Comment: $url="http://example.com";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}

Answer (score 0):

A simple PHP HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+, supports invalid HTML, and provides a very easy way to handle HTML elements. Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery. Extract contents from HTML in a single line.

Here is the link to get it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

...and here is the official web site: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

For basic HTML elements you can use http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ to parse DOM content (it handle jquery like CSS selectors, functions like `attr`, `find`). Here is example howto use selectors with PhpQuery http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Selectors.

For properties, it depends:

- Some kind of regexp if they are in Javascripts or something else,
- If they are in data attributes and you know attributes name, then you can get that json string and simply run `json_decode` php function on it.